# How to fetch the key value from an array in MongoDb?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, find

I have the below document structure in MongoDB.

```
 [
  {
    "network_type": "ex",
    "rack": [
      {
        "xxxx": {
          "asn": 111111,
          "nodes": {
            "business": [
              "tt550abcc1eb01"
            ],
            "master": [
              "tt550abcc1eb02"
            ]
          },
          "region": "ex-01",
          "zone": "01a"
        },
        "yyyy": {
          "asn": 22222,
          "nodes": {
            "business": [
              "er44abcc1eb28"
            ]
          },
          "region": "ex-02",
          "zone": "02a"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The names inside nodes array of business, master are unique.
Is it possible to find the nodes array details by just passing the value "er44abcc1eb28" ?
I tried the below query but it didn't work out.
Please help.

```
     db.collection.find({"rack.$[].nodes.$[]": "er44abcc1eb28"},{})
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/1yH_q0-9Iik

Answer (score 1):

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FZp3BzeokCf)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {              //Reshape the array
    "$unwind": "$rack"
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "racks": { //To handle dynamic key i.e xxxx, yyyy
        "$objectToArray": "$rack"
      }
    }
  },
  {.            //Reshape to match the element
    $unwind: "$racks"
  },
  {
    "$match": { //match condition
      "racks.v.nodes.business": "er44abcc1eb28"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {   //Group the results incase there are more matches per id
      "_id": "$_id",
      data: {
        $push: "$racks"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "rack": { //Reshape the data to the original form
        "$arrayToObject": "$data"
      }
    }
  }
]) //To understand, remove each stage and check, refer the documentation.
```